# Spring NoClassDefFoundError on org/springframework/transaction/support/TransactionSynchronization

Tags: spring, noclassdeffounderror

Spring JMS is working against me, as the title say I get a NoClassDefFoundError, below you find the code.

```
import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.Queue;
import javax.jms.Session;

import org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate;
import org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate102;
import org.springframework.jms.core.MessageCreator;

public class JMSQueueSender {
    private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;
    private Queue queue;

    public void setConnectionFactory(ConnectionFactory cf) {
        this.jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate102(cf, false);
    }

    public void setQueue(Queue queue) {
        this.queue = queue;
    }

    public void simpleSend() throws Exception {
        this.jmsTemplate.send(this.queue, new MessageCreator() {
            public Message createMessage(Session session) throws JMSException {
                return session.createTextMessage("hello queue world");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This is also the example code, I have a working code with IBM, but I'm trying to change it for a Spring JMS, but it isn't working. Can someone help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you need to add `spring-tx.jar` (or `org.springframework.transaction-*.jar` with new style of names) to the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking your JAVA_HOME and CLASSPATH settings.

Comment: Where I'm looking for? I checked them, java_home is pointed to my JDK and the classpath is pointed to IBM and the bin directory of my JDK